# PHP DOM add new line between radio buttons

Tags: php

I want to add a new line between radio button.

I was able to add text to my radio buttons but the createTextNode of "\n" does work... although '\n' shows up on HTML... but the "\n" doesn't nor does it drop a line.

```
$showXLS = new DOMDocument();

$showXLS->formatOutput = true;
$showXLS->preserveWhiteSpace = false;
$sXLSSpan = $showXLS->createElement('Span');
$showXLS->appendChild($sXLSSpan);
$sXLSSpan->setAttribute('id','saveOptions');
$sXLSSpan->setAttribute('style','VISIBILITY');

$sXLSDiv = $showXLS->createElement('Div');
$sXLSSpan->appendChild($sXLSDiv);
$sXLSDiv->setAttribute('id','showingOptions');
$sXLSDiv->setAttribute('align','right');

$sXLSForm = $showXLS->createElement('Form');
$sXLSDiv->appendChild($sXLSForm);
$sXLSForm->setAttribute('id','sXLSForm');
$sXLSForm->setAttribute('action','printTest.php');
$sXLSForm->setAttribute('method','POST');

$sXLSInput1Text = $showXLS->createElement('label','<b>Save Directory</b>');
$sXLSForm->appendChild($sXLSInput1Text);
$sXLSInput1Text->appendChild($showXLS->createTextNode("\n"));


$sXLSInput1 = $showXLS->createElement('input');
$sXLSInput1Text->appendChild($sXLSInput1);
$sXLSInput1->setAttribute('type','radio');
$sXLSInput1->setAttribute('name','save');
$sXLSInput1->setAttribute('value','saveDirectory');
$sXLSInput1->setAttribute('id','saveDirectory');


$sXLSInput2Text = $showXLS->createElement('label','Save Email');
$sXLSForm->appendChild($sXLSInput2Text);
$sXLSInput2Text->appendChild($showXLS->createTextNode("\n"));
```

/////////////// new line here

```
$sXLSInput2 = $showXLS->createElement('input');
$sXLSInput2Text->appendChild($sXLSInput2);
$sXLSInput2->setAttribute('type','radio');
$sXLSInput2->setAttribute('name','save');
$sXLSInput2->setAttribute('value','saveEmail');
$sXLSInput2->setAttribute('onClick','getMore()');
```

Comment: HTML doesn't honor \r and \n linebreak chars. They're treated the same as a space character. You need to use html breaks: `<br>`.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
<br/>
or
createElement("br");
```

\n doesn't have any value in html

Comment: $br = $showXLS->createElement('br'); Yes thank you so Much hendr1x what a time saver.   when i googled it they told me to do it with createTextNode.